# When i try running a unit test using intern .. i get the error - TypeError: deps.map is not a function

Tags: unit-testing, dojo, intern

i am new to intern, and when i try running a unit test with the command-node client.js config= i get the below error-

```
  TypeError: deps.map is not a function
  at resolveDeps  <node_modules\dojo\loader.ts:779:4>
  at defineModule  <node_modules\dojo\loader.ts:796:4>
  at onLoadCallback  <node_modules\dojo\loader.ts:748:3>
  at <node_modules\dojo\loader.ts:848:4>
  at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete]  <fs.js:380:3>
```

This is the define function used-

```
define(["intern/order!../../routes/vehciles","intern!object","intern!chai/assert","intern!tdd"],function(test1,registerSuite,assert,tdd)
{
tdd.suite("test testSuite1",function(){

    tdd.test("test tokenTest",function(){
        console.log('testing the token Service');
        var token = 'Bearer';
        var result = test1.validateBearerToken(token);
        assert.equal(result, 'true' , 'TestPassed : This is a valid token');
    });
});

});
```

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: vehciles has a spelling mistake.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29310649/typeerror-deps-map-is-not-a-function-in-resolvedepmaps-of-node-modules-dojo

Comment: What does your test config look like?