# "TypeError: deps.map is not a function" importing URI.js from intern.js unit tests

Tags: javascript, intern

I am getting a build error when trying to use [URI.js](https://medialize.github.io/URI.js/) from intern.js unit tests. I saw ["TypeError: deps.map is not a function" in resolveDepMaps() of node_modules/dojo/dojo.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29310649/14731) but none of the answers seem to apply to my case.

- I posted a testcase here: https://github.com/cowwoc/intern-import-urijs
- I posted a bug report here: https://github.com/theintern/intern/issues/708

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting [jason0x43](https://github.com/theintern/intern/issues/708#issuecomment-270720242):

> One of the dependencies in the attached project, punycode, uses an AMD define call of the form define(id, factory). This is a case that isn't currently handled by Intern's internal loader.
>
> The easiest fix would be to use an alternative AMD loader for tests, such as the normal Dojo loader or RequireJS. For example, to use requirejs, install requirejs as a project dependency and add the following property to the test config:
>
> ```
> loaders: {
>     'host-node': '../../node_modules/requirejs'
> },
> ```

This workaround fixed the problem for me.